# how to play two audio files with same id with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, audio

i have two audio files with progress bar and both having same id:

```
<audio id="player" src="<?=base_url('mp3/'.$rec->file)?>"></audio>
                    </p>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="play">
                            <svg style='font-size: 1.3em' class="bi bi-play-fill" width="1em" height="1em" 
                                viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M11.596 8.697l-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 010 1.393z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="pause">
                            <svg style='font-size: 1.3em' class="bi bi-pause-fill" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" 
                                fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M5.5 3.5A1.5 1.5 0 017 5v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0V5a1.5 1.5 0 011.5-1.5zm5 0A1.5 1.5 0 0112 5v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0V5a1.5 1.5 0 011.5-1.5z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <progress style="height: 4px;border: none;width: 300px;max-width: 330px" id="seekbar"  value="0" max="1">ssss
```

And Here's js

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$('#play').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('player'.).play();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('player').pause();
});

$('#player').on('timeupdate', function() {
    $('#seekbar').attr("value", this.currentTime / this.duration);
});
</script>
```

now i am able to play the first audio file but cannot play second file

> how do i do that?????

if there's any other solution like looping ids or anything just tell me because i am a noob in js

[image]

Comment: "_both having same id_" `id`s need to be unique, use classes maybe?

Comment: well then i have to use different ids for buttons too..

Comment: and i am a noob in js so i dont really know how to loop it

Comment: @kerbholz sorry i am editing that

Comment: so is there any other solution?

Comment: Use classes and maybe `data` attributes to relate the elements

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` only returns the first match, if you want to get all matches, use 
`document.querySelectorAll` instead.

Here's how you should do it

```js
$('#play').on('click', function() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('#player')].forEach(e => e.play());
});

$('#pause').on('click', function() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('#player')].forEach(e => e.pause());
});
```

As kerbholz mentioned, `id` should be unique. If it meant to have multiple instances, consider to use `class` instead.

Comment: what's `e` in this?

Comment: `e` is each element with the id `player`, since you're dealing with multiple instances(also works for single element), which can be named as whatever you want. Also [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a loop function for arrays

Comment: it is working  but there's only one bug which is that it plays both audio files at the same time

Comment: @AzanKorejo It's not the expected behavior? Then you have to loop through them one by one, play each one after the previous one is finished.

Comment: look at the picture given  in the question

Comment: So you want to play them one by one with that UI also working? That's a whole feature and couldn't be done in several lines of code. By now you've already got all the `audio` tags by `[...document.querySelectorAll('#player')]` and you should at least try to implement it yourself.